# Convert between ISO week and a normal date

Tags: time-date

How can you convert between ISO year-week-day and an elisp date that can be sent to, e.g., `format-time-string`? I do not want to go via a string representation.

I found the following old question on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055504/iso-emacs-elisp-to-determines-dates-corresponding-to-first-last-days-of-a-week/, but haven't been able to find a published answer.

Comment: What is normal date? 31/03/1978, 31 Марта 1978 года, 03/31/1978, 31 de marzo de 1978?

Comment: I clarified what I mean with a "normal date".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on your own answer, here is another way to do it.

```el
(require 'cal-iso)

(defun iso-week-to-time (year week day)
  (pcase-let ((`(,m ,d ,y)
               (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute
                (calendar-iso-to-absolute (list week day year)))))
    (encode-time 0 0 0 d m y)))

(format-time-string "%F" (iso-week-to-time 2018 32 2))
;; => "2018-08-07"
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is my own solution to the question.

`calendar-iso-to-absolute` and `calendar-gregorian-from absolute` converts the list `(year week weekday)` to the list `(month day year)` which is transformed to `(0 0 0 day month year)` and processed by `encode-time`. The result is an elisp time value that can be processed by `format-time`.

Example:

```
(format-time-string "%F" (iso-week-to-time 2018 32 1)) % Monday week 32 in 2018
"2018-08-06"
```

There should be simpler solutions as this is a kludge, especially the permutation of the list.

```
(defun iso-week-to-time(year week day)
  "Convert ISO year, week, day to elisp time value."
  (apply #'encode-time
         (append '(0 0 0)
                 (-select-by-indices
                  '(1 0 2)
                  (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute (calendar-iso-to-absolute
                                                     (list week day year)))))))

(defun iso-beginning-of-week(year week)
  "Convert ISO year, week to elisp time for first day (Monday) of week."
  (iso-week-to-time year week 1))

(defun iso-end-of-week(year week)
  "Convert ISO year, week to elisp time for last day (Sunday) of week."
  (iso-week-to-time year week 7))
```